# How to get user input for multiple arguements in a function in Python3

Tags: python

Essentially I want to use the input() function to take user input for multiple arguements in this function and return the value

```
def object_distance(f,di):

    do = 1/((1/f)-(1/di))

    return do

odistance = input(object_distance())
print("The object distance is: {0:3.1f} cm".format(odistance))
```

Comment: Could you give an input/output example?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the input *first*, and *then* call the function.

```
a1 = input("Enter f: ")
a2 = input("Enter di: ")

# TODO Convert the strings a1 and a2 to values of the appropriate
# type for object_distance.

distance = object_distance(a1, a2)
```

The argument to `input` is just a string to display as a prompt, not a function (and certainly not a *call* to that function) that it "works with" to determine how many arguments are needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can call input multiple times.

```
f_input = input('Enter f:')
di_input = input('Enter di:')
odistance = object_distance(f_input, di_input)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enter 2 values one after another. I also cast the input to int when calling the function.

```
def object_distance(f, di):
    do = 1/((1/f)-(1/di))
    return do
    
f, di = input ('Input 2 values separated by a space').split()
odistance = object_distance(int(f) , int(di))
print("The object distance is: {0:3.1f} cm".format(odistance))
```

Output

````
Input 2 values separated by a space
7 9
The object distance is: 31.5 cm```
````